# R error using package tm (text-mining)

Tags: r, text-mining

I am attempting to use the tm package to convert a vector of text strings to a corpus element.

My code looks something like this

```
Corpus(d1$Yes)
```

where `d1$Yes` is a factor with 124 levels, each containing a text string.

For example, `d1$Yes[246] = "So we can get the boat out!"`

I'm receiving the following error:

```
"Error: inherits(x, "Source") is not TRUE"
```

I'm not sure how to remedy this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to tell Corpus what kind of source you are using.  Try:

```
Corpus(VectorSource(d1$Yes))
```